# how to add id and class to select box in Cakephp

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.1

i am new to cakephp so i dont know how to i do this ... i have a view page in which there is a select box in which time zone is displaying

```
  <?php

    echo $this->Timezone->select('timezone');

     ?>
```

i want to add the 'id' , 'class' and label to it .. and if label isnt possible then its okk ..but the id and class is very important

what i want actually my select box is this

```
<label for="validation-select" class="label">Select</label>
<select id="validation-select" name="validation-select" class="select validate[required]">
```

or if i want to add the timezone in this i dont know how can i do this

**helper class**

http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/MarkAlanEvans/2009/12/17/updated-timezone-helper

Answer (score 2):

```
$month = array('1' => 'January', '2' => 'February', '3' => 'March', '4' => 'April', '5' => 'May', '6' => 'June', '7' => 'July', '8' => 'August', '9' => 'September', '10' => 'October', '11' => 'November', '12' => 'December');


 echo $this->Form->select('month', $month, array('class' => 'form-control month', 'placeholder' => 'Month', 'id' => 'month', 'empty' => 'Select Month'));
```

Answer (score 0):

### Use the options array

A select generated by the form helper will already have an id of the format "ModelField" - if you want to override it just specify it in the options array (the second argument):

```
echo $this->Form->input('timezone', array(
    'options' => $options
    'id' => 'foo',
    'class' => 'bar'
));
```

In the same way you can modify/add all tag attributes.

Since you're not directly using the form helper - simply modify the Timezone helper to permit passing another argument, and add pass through to the call to `Form->input`.

Comment: well this is not the answer i need.. i know how can i generate a select box ... what my intention is i want to add css class to my timezone helper which i am using ...i mean add to this  echo $this->Timezone->select('timezone');

Comment: ok i am adding the helper if you are asking for this but please dont give -1 :p

Comment: Unless you're asking someone to write the code for you, you should already have an answer you can use - good luck =).